# Why is possible to write a function outside a class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I don't understand why is possible to write a function outside a class in Kotlin ? Is that a good practice ?

For example, it's possible in Kotlin to write a function outside my `MainActivity` class :

```
fun hello(){}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        hello()
    }
}
```

In Java, this is impossible! That's not how an object-oriented language works normally, right?

In the documentation, they talk of **Local Functions** for the classic function and **Member Functions** for the function defined inside a class or object but they don't explain when it's better to use one or the other.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope Found some documentation that might interest you.

Comment: My rather-uneducated take on it, is that declaring a top-level function would be akin to declaring a static function in Java.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand why it's better sometimes to use a Local Functions instead of Member Functions

Comment: Think about "utility" functions that don't need to belong to any class. And extensions functions (see Kotlin docs).

Comment: yes but I can create an Utiliy class for that no ?

Comment: You can create a Utility class, sure, but why do you think it's a good idea to do that?

Comment: Because you can share it with other classes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You can call a top-level function from other classes too.

Comment: It's actually much easier to create "Utility Classes".  You just create a package, and add all your functions there.  Then all you need to do import my.package.* to access them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, **it is a good practice** to create package-level functions **if** the function logic is independent of properties and lifecycle of a class. Example:

- a function to convert miles per gallon to kilometers per litre is independent of any object and fits well as package-level.
- otoh, a function to cancel reservation would naturally be associated with a specifc reservation object and fits well inside such a class.

The main benefit of a package-level function is simplicity (ergo better maintainability): callers of your function don't need to declare and create an object to call the function.
(If your package-level function needs to be called from Java code, this benefit is lost because the Java calling code has to use a class name that is generated by Kotlin.)

***IMPORTANT: Although you don't have a class lexical scope for your function, the Single-Responsibility Principle (SRP) still applies***. Do not create a Kotlin source file, say Util.kt, and bloat it up with functions that lack cohesion, that is, functions that do unrelated things.

Answer (score 75):

> In Java, this is impossible! That's not how an object-oriented language works normally, right?

Just stop for a second and reconsider the nature of java's static method. A class is supposed to be a blueprint for objects, describe their behavior and state. But you can call a static method without creating any instances.

How does that fit into the object-oriented picture? How does a static method "belong" to the class it's declared in?

Actually, static methods are top-level functions and the class only provides a namespace for them. Speaking strictly from the OOP perspective you bring up, they are a hack. But you got used to them over the years so you don't feel that anymore.

In contrast to that, Kotlin allows you to declare top-level functions without forcing you to couple their name to a class. Sometimes you expressly want to couple a top-level function to a class, and that's what companion objects are for in Kotlin.

Comment: "...without misusing the class for namespacing." - Does that mean that function name should be unique in the project ?

Comment: No, function names are qualified with package names.

Comment: Not to mention that another successful and predating-Java OO language (C++) supports free functions as well. Forcing one to shove utility, static functions into a class has always been a nuisance.

Comment: C++ pretty much had to support free functions for historical reasons so we can't infer anything about how the the language would have been designed if the burden of C compatibility wasn't a factor. See [Why Java does not allow function definitions to be present outside of the class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185159/318658)

Comment: @ggorlen The argument there isn't much sounder, either: it just states there's class files and their advantages. A similar file could equally exist if the compilation unit was a file and not just one class (and that's exactly what Kotlin does -- there's a class file mapping to a .kt file). The class thing is just as much an artifact of the original OOP focus of Java as C++ design is the artifact of its assembler-C legacy.

Comment: Do such funs compile into Java static methods?

Comment: Yes, they become static methods in the `FilenameKt` class.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, this is good practice. Kotlin is not a purely object-oriented language, so it's not obligated to follow how "an object-oriented language works normally" (even though other object-oriented languages, such as C++, Ruby and Python, also allow top-level functions).

It's better to use a top-level function when the logic of this function does not clearly belong to any class.