# Unsure as to why there is a class, interface or enum expected error?

Tags: java

I have just started creating this program and I am trying to make a method outside of the main class. I researched the error and it says there are too many curly brackets outside the main function.

I was just wondering if it was actually possible to have a public static function outside of a main class?

```
class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


}


public static void plusOne(){

}
```

Comment: Every method must be in a class (or interface). It doesn't have to be in your *main* class, but it has to be in something.

Answer (score 3):

Think of a class as a collection of code. You can have as many classes as you want. But you can not put code outside of a class and there is no reason you should want to.

Comment: Or note that Java is an object-oriented language. Everything is an object and objects are just instances of a class. Methods are applied on objects. Functions belong to concepts that are represented by classes. It makes no sense to have methods/functions outside of classes in Java.

Comment: "*there is no reason you should want to*." This is not true. Kotlin allows this, and I consider that to be a well-designed language.

Comment: @akuzminykh Being an object-oriented language doesn't preclude having standalone functions. It's a language design choice.

Comment: @akuzminykh "*Methods are applied on objects*". how about static methods?

Comment: @khelwood Ok. Rather give the OP the answer "Every method must be in a class" because that's why. Or "Think of a class as a collection of code".

Comment: @Michael What do you think is the difference between a *function* and a *method*?

Comment: @Michael. To clarify my point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015268/13373270. Having a method outside a class does not gain you any additional functionality, it just makes for arguably cleaner code, more honest to an OOP approach.