# What are the differences between a companion object function and package level functions?

Tags: kotlin, static, companion-object

Whats the difference between having a function on a companion object and having the function at package level?

```
class Foo {

    companion object {
        fun bar() = println("bar")
    }
}

fun bar() = println("bar")
```

You can call both pretty similar

```
class B {

    fun print() {
        Foo.bar()
    }

    fun print2() {
        bar()
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of difference you want to know? Bytecode? Sematics? Syntax? Practical usage? Memory consumtion?

Comment: BTW: "on file function" is referenced in docs as [high order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Comment: mostly Practical usage, Memory @Neo

Comment: @Neo ? That's not what a higher order function is, it's a function that can take other functions as arguments and stuff, right? "On-file functions" or functions outside class bodies don't have to be like that. I think they're called simply top-level functions.

Comment: i call them package level functions

Comment: @user You're right. The actual name is [top level function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope), also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013996/why-is-possible-to-write-a-function-outside-a-class-in-kotlin)

Comment: Is there something specific from the documentation you're not understanding? This is a big topic to explain, but all the basics are in the documentation, so not sure what you're looking for in an answer.